# heap sort using binary tree

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-tree, bitwise-operators

I was trying to figure out a code about heap sort using binary tree that I saw on stackoverflow.com,

here is the code:

```
//Heap Sort using Linked List
//This is the raw one
//This getRoot function will replace the root with number in the last node, after the main prints the largest number in the heap
//The heapSort function will reconstruct the heap
//addNode function is as same as in binary search tree
//Note addNode and heapSort are recursive functions
//You may wonder about the for loop used in main, this actually tells the depth of the tree (i.e log base2 N)
//With this value these functions find where to trverse whether left or right(direction), with help of macro GETBIT (0-left,1-right)


#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define GETBIT(num,pos) (num >> pos & 1)

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
typedef struct node node;

int nodes;
node *first, *tmp, *current;

void addNode(node *,node *,int);
void swap(int *, int *);
void getRoot(node *, int);
void heapSort(node *);

int main()
{
    int num;
    int cont,i,j;

    while(1)                                                //It gets number from user if previous value is non zero number
    {
        printf("Enter a number\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if(!num)                                            //i'm using 0 as terminating condition to stop adding nodes
            break;                                          //edit this as you wish

        current = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(current ==  0)
            return 0;

        current->data = num;
        nodes++;

        for(i=nodes,j=-1; i; i >>= 1,j++);

        if(first == 0)
        {
            first = current;
            first->left = 0;
            first->right = 0;
        }
        else
            addNode(first,first,j-1);

        printf("Need to add more\n");

    }
    printf("Number of nodes added : %d\n",nodes);

    while(nodes)
    {
        printf(" %d -> ",first->data);                                        //prints the largest number in the heap

        for(i=nodes,j=-1; i; i >>= 1,j++);                                    //Updating the height of the tree
        getRoot(first,j-1);
        nodes--;

        heapSort(first);
    }       

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    *a = *a + *b;
    *b = *a - *b;
    *a = *a - *b;
}

void addNode(node *tmp1,node *parent, int pos)
{
    int dirxn = GETBIT(nodes,pos);                                   // 0 - go left, 1 - go right

    if(!pos)
    {
        if(dirxn)
            tmp1->right = current;
        else
            tmp1->left = current;

        current->left = 0;
        current->right = 0;

        if(current->data > tmp1->data)
            swap(&current->data, &tmp1->data);
    }

    else
        if(dirxn)
            addNode(tmp1->right,tmp1,pos-1);
        else
            addNode(tmp1->left,tmp1,pos-1);

    if(tmp1->data > parent->data)
        swap(&parent->data,&tmp1->data);
}

void getRoot(node *tmp,int pos)
{
    int dirxn;

    if(nodes == 1)
        return ;

    while(pos)
    {
        dirxn = GETBIT(nodes,pos);

        if(dirxn)
            tmp = tmp->right;
        else
            tmp = tmp->left;
        pos--;
    }

    dirxn = GETBIT(nodes,pos);

    if(dirxn)
    {
        first->data = tmp->right->data;
        free(tmp->right);
        tmp->right = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        first->data = tmp->left->data;
        free(tmp->left);
        tmp->left = 0;
    }
}

void heapSort(node *tmp)
{
    if(!tmp->right && !tmp->left)
        return;

    if(!tmp->right)
    {
        if(tmp->left->data > tmp->data)
            swap(&tmp->left->data, &tmp->data);
    }
    else
    {
        if(tmp->right->data > tmp->left->data)
        {
            if(tmp->right->data > tmp->data)
            {
                swap(&tmp->right->data, &tmp->data);
                heapSort(tmp->right);
            }
        }           
        else
        {
            if(tmp->left->data > tmp->data)
            {
                swap(&tmp->left->data, &tmp->data);
                heapSort(tmp->left);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand the right shift operator
so I tried to replace `for(i=nodes,j=-1; i; i >>= 1,j++);`
with

```
int o, j=0;
for(int i=1;;i=pow(2, j)){
    if(nodes<i){
        o = j-1;
        break;
    }
    j+=1;
}
```

but I don't understand `dirxn = GETBIT(nodes,pos);`

my question is what does this do?
and can anyone tell me what should I do to replace this with something without a shift operator?

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The `>>=` is a right-shift operator, not a left-shift operator.  It effectively divides by 2.  Your loop condition is emphatically not the same as the original.  The original contains a test `i != 0` (abbreviated `i`); yours has no condition.  That's worrying.

Comment: sorry, I fixed the right shift. the loop is working fine.

Comment: I observe that the macro `#define GETBIT(num,pos) (num >> pos & 1)` is riskily written.  It should be at minimum `#define GETBIT(num,pos) ((num) >> (pos) & 1)` to ensure that if `num` or `pos` is some sort of arithmetic expression, the condition is the same. I think it would benefit from another set of parentheses: `#define GETBIT(num,pos) ((num) >> (pos)) & 1)` to clarify that the `&` applies to the result of the shift rather than to `(pos)` per se. Given the actual usage, it is OK, but general-purpose macros should use enough parentheses to ensure that they are safe against plausible misuse.

Comment: The `swap()` function `void swap(int *a,int *b) { *a = *a + *b; *b = *a - *b; *a = *a - *b; }` is dubious.  Given big enough values, it will (wholly unnecessarily) incur signed integer overflow leading to undefined behaviour.  It should use a temporary variable: `void swap(int *a,int *b) { int t = *a; *a = *b; *b = t; }` which uses 4 pointer dereferences and 3 assignments, contrasted with 9 pointer dereferences, 3 assignments and 3 (potentially overflowing) arithmetic operations.

Comment: There really shouldn't be a need for the global variable `current` which is accessed from `addNode()`.  It complicates the thought processes required to understand what is going on — you add a node but don't explicitly pass the node to be added to the function that adds it.  Yuck!  Then there's the loop `for(i=nodes,j=-1; i; i >>= 1,j++);` written on a single line.  K&R pointed out that a null loop body like that is best put on a line on its own so that it is clearer that the loop has a null body.  That loop appears twice, too.  Maybe it should be a function, probably a `static inline` one.

Comment: I don't think that's very good code to be learning from — other perhaps than 'how not to code a heap sort'.

Comment: @jak — When I compile: `void swap(int *a, int *b) { *a ^= (*b ^= (*a ^= *b)); }`, I get a warning from GCC: `error: operation on ‘*a’ may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]` highlighting the first `^=` operator.  That isn't safe, in other words, because there are no sequence points before the semicolon and you assign to `*a` twice in the expression.

Comment: @jak: It isn't the same — with it written out as 3 statements, there is a sequence point at each semicolon, but when written as a single expression there aren't the necessary sequence points to ensure reliable evaluation.  You can't safely assign to the same variable twice between sequence points, which the contracted, single-expression version of the code attempts to do.

Comment: @jak: And what if `a` and `b` point to the same object? Don't try to be clever with swap. It's error-prone and much slower than necessary. It only made sense, if it ever did, on CPUs without multiple registers.

Comment: @jak — I always compile with `-Werror` so any warnings are treated as errors because if the compiler deigns to warn about something, it is (almost) invariably an incipient bug that it has spotted, something that should be fixed. I choose to regard all compiler warnings as errors. The addition of parentheses to an expression does not add a sequence point.  Using a comma operator, or a ternary operator, or either `&&` or `||`, or making a function call — all those create sequence points.  AFAICR, no other operators create sequence points — other than the semicolon to mark the end of a statement.

Comment: @someone: my above comment about trying to be clever with swap also applies to yours. If a and b are the same, swap should be a no-op, but yours isn't. Just use a temporary. It's cleaner, cheaper and most important, not buggy.